# Average per category per last N round in Pandas and lag it

Tags: pandas

I have a following problem.
I want to compute mean of last 2 observations per name and round and lag it. See following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'name':["a","a","a","a","b","b","c" ] , 'value':[6,5,4,3,1,2,1] , 
                        'round':[1,2,3,4,1,2,1 ]})
```

Desired output is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'name':["a","a","a","a","b","b","c" ] , 'value':[6,5,4,3,1,2,1] ,
                        'round':[1,2,3,4,1,2,1 ], 'mean_last_2':["NaN","NaN",5.5,4.5,"NaN","NaN","NaN"]})
```

I tried this, but got "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shift'":

```
df['mean_last_2'] = df.groupby("name")['value'].apply(lambda x: 
                                                         x.tail(2).mean().shift(1))
```

How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
 df['mean_last_2'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2).mean().shift())
```

Output:

```
  name  value  round  mean_last_2
0    a      6      1          NaN
1    a      5      2          NaN
2    a      4      3          5.5
3    a      3      4          4.5
4    b      1      1          NaN
5    b      2      2          NaN
6    c      1      1          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
df.groupby("name").apply(lambda d: d.assign(mean_last_2 = d['value'].rolling(2).mean().shift()))
```

to get

```
        name    value   round   mean_last_2
name                    
a   0   a       6       1       NaN
    1   a       5       2       NaN
    2   a       4       3       5.5
    3   a       3       4       4.5
b   4   b       1       1       NaN
    5   b       2       2       NaN
c   6   c       1       1       NaN
```